# Is Al badi a name of Allah ?

Tags: authenticity, asma-ul-husna, salafi

This verse in Quran بَدِيعُ ٱلسَّمَـٰوَٲتِ وَٱلۡأَرۡضِ‌ۖ وَإِذَا قَضَىٰٓ أَمۡرً۬ا فَإِنَّمَا يَقُولُ لَهُ ۥ كُن فَيَكُونُ Al-Baqarah 2:117 saying "The Originator of the heavens and the earth. When He decrees a matter, He only says to it: "Be!" - and it is".Can we derive Al badi from this? But in a list of names of Allah  Sheikh uthymeen didn't mentioned Al-badi

Comment: Which name you mean al-badi البادي، البادئ or al-badi' البديع? If al-Othaymeen quoted a list then that shows only his view. In the sum scholars quoted more than 200 names of Allah.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I think she meant البديع as from the ayah.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference of opinions on whether *Al-Badee'* (Arabic: البديع) is one of the names of Allah. The name generally means the Originator.

The majority of scholars do not consider *Al-Badee'* to be one of Allah's names, but rather the phrase `بَدِيعُ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ` is considered to be an attribute, based on the verse you quoted:

> بَدِيعُ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ وَإِذَا قَضَى أَمْرًا فَإِنَّمَا
>   يَقُولُ لَهُ كُنْ فَيَكُونُ
>
> Originator of the heavens and the earth. When He decrees a matter, He
>   only says to it, "Be," and it is.
>
> <sub>— [Qur'an 2:117](https://quran.com/2/117/)</sub>

in addition to this verse:

> بَدِيعُ السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ أَنَّى يَكُونُ لَهُ وَلَدٌ وَلَمْ
>   تَكُنْ لَهُ صَاحِبَةٌ وَخَلَقَ كُلَّ شَيْءٍ وَهُوَ بِكُلِّ شَيْءٍ
>   عَلِيمٌ
>
> [He is] Originator of the heavens and the earth. How could He have a
>   son when He does not have a companion and He created all things? And
>   He is, of all things, Knowing.
>
> <sub>— [Qur'an 6:101](https://quran.com/6/101/)</sub>

There are, however, scholars (e.g., [Ibn Hajar al-Asqalani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Hajar_al-Asqalani), and [Al-Bayhaqi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Bayhaqi)) who consider *Al-Badee'* to be one of Allah's names.

An authentic hadith in Sahih Al-Bukhari stipulates that Allah has ninety nine names, but the hadith does not mention the names:

> حَدَّثَنَا عَلِيُّ بْنُ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ، حَدَّثَنَا سُفْيَانُ، قَالَ
>   حَفِظْنَاهُ مِنْ أَبِي الزِّنَادِ عَنِ الأَعْرَجِ، عَنْ أَبِي
>   هُرَيْرَةَ، رِوَايَةً قَالَ: لِلَّهِ تِسْعَةٌ وَتِسْعُونَ اسْمًا،
>   مِائَةٌ إِلاَّ وَاحِدًا، لاَ يَحْفَظُهَا أَحَدٌ إِلاَّ دَخَلَ
>   الْجَنَّةَ، وَهْوَ وَتْرٌ يُحِبُّ الْوَتْرَ
>
> Narrated Abu Huraira: Allah has ninety-nine names, i.e., one hundred
>   minus one, and whoever believes in their meanings and acts
>   accordingly, will enter Paradise; and Allah is *witr* (one) and loves
>   *the witr* (i.e., odd numbers).
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Al-Bukhari Book 80, Hadith 105](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/80/105/)</sub>

A similar hadith is in [Sahih Muslim, Book 48, Hadith 6](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/48/6/), and another in [Jami' at-Tirmidhi, Book 48, Hadith 139](https://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/139/) convey the same meaning. There is, however, another hadith in [Jami' at-Tirmidhi, Book 48, Hadith 138](https://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/138/), which stipulates some of the names, including *Al-Badee'*. There is no authentic chain of narration with the addition of the names in this version; hence, the difference of opinions about this name (among some others).